# How to scrape information from diary letterboxd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As I said in the title, I'm scraping some information on Letterboxd and need help.

I already have a function where I can scrape all info that I need (such as name, date, cast etc) from a URL like this  https://letterboxd.com/film/when-marnie-was-there/

The point is that I also want to scrape all the movies I've already watched (which you can find here https://letterboxd.com/gfac/films/diary/) and after that use their URL to run my other function.

But looking into the devtools on my browser I can't find the complete movie URL in my diary. So I was thinking if I can extract one of the two pieces of info highlighted in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rMdT.png). If yes, I can after concatenate

```
"https://letterboxd.com/" + "film/when-marnie-was-there/"
```

and run my other function.

This is what I got until now:

```
def teste(url):

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

elem = soup.find_all("h3", {"class": "headline-3 prettify"})[0]

return elem

a = teste("https://letterboxd.com/gfac/films/diary/")
print(a)

<h3 class="headline-3 prettify"><a href="/gfac/film/when-marnie-was-there/">When Marnie Was There</a></h3>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, so extract the `href` value with `.get('href)` and concat with base url. To generate a `list` of urls that you can iterate to scrape use a `list comprehension`:

```
diary_urls = ['https://letterboxd.com' + a.get('href').replace('/gfac','') for a in soup.select('h3>a[href]')]
```

or with more compact with slicing instead of `.replace()`:

```
diary_urls = [base_url + a.get('href')[5:] for a in soup.select('h3>a[href]')]
```

**Note:** *You could go with find_all(), I used `select` and [`css selectors`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) for convenience here and to select the elements more specific - Only direct `<h3>` following `<a>` with `href` attribute*

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
base_url = 'https://letterboxd.com'
r = requests.get(f'{base_url}/gfac/films/diary/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

diary_urls = [base_url + a.get('href')[5:] for a in soup.select('h3>a[href]')]

data = []
for url in diary_urls[:2]:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    data.append({
        'title': soup.select_one('#film-page-wrapper h1').get_text(),
        'cast':soup.select_one('#tab-cast p').get_text(',',strip=True),
        'what ever':'you like to scrape'
    })
    
data
```

##### Output

```
[{'title': 'When Marnie Was There', 'cast': 'Sara Takatsuki,Kasumi Arimura,Nanako Matsushima,Susumu Terajima,Toshie Negishi,Ryôko Moriyama,Kazuko Yoshiyuki,Hitomi Kuroki,Hiroyuki Morisaki,Takuma Otoo,Hana Sugisaki,Bari Suzuki,Shigeyuki Totsugi,Ken Yasuda,Yo Oizumi,Yuko Kaida', 'what ever': 'you like to scrape'}, {'title': 'The Fly', 'cast': 'Jeff Goldblum,Geena Davis,John Getz,Joy Boushel,Leslie Carlson,George Chuvalo,Michael Copeman,David Cronenberg,Carol Lazare,Shawn Hewitt,Typhoon', 'what ever': 'you like to scrape'},...]
```

Comment: wow! 
You just simplified my two functions into a few lines of code. It's amazing!

Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Happy to help, but just to be clear, there is nothing wrong with functions, on the contrary, use them where you can, this is just a minimal, reproducible example to show a direction. Feel free to adapt it so that it is as generic and modular as possible for your task, even with functions, because that is great practice.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `diary` link that you provided, the following code works at retreiving and creating a list of film urls from that page. You will have to find a way to provide the code with the second page of your diary, and third or fourth as it grows.

```
url = 'https://letterboxd.com/gfac/films/diary'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

links = [link['href'] for link in soup.find_all('a')]
films = [url[0:22] + i[5:] for i in list(dict.fromkeys(links)) if '/gfac/film/' in i]
```

`urls` is created by finding every `<a>` tag within `soup` and filtering out every instance of `href` (hyperlinks in html). This results in a list of many unwanted links and duplicates.

`films` is a list of film urls created by first filtering out duplicate links, then filtering anything that does not redirect to a film page (which is denoted by `/film/` after the base url). It scrapes away `/gfac/` in the string, and finally adds the letterboxd base url to the beginning of each item creating a proper link.